# vim: open file under cursor in read-only (no swapfile)

Tags: vim, readonly, header-file

so, we all know of `gf`, `:find`, etc, but is there a read-only equivalent, the `:view` to their `:edit`?

i just want an easy shortcut to open system headers without creating a swapfile

`:find +set\ noma\ ro <cfile>` still creates a swapfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [`:noswapfile`](https://vimhelp.org/recover.txt.html#%3Anoswapfile) modifier to open the file with `:find` without creating a swapfile:

```
:nos find <cfile>
```

Comment: so i did `nn hf :nos fin +setl\ ro\ noma <cfile><cr>
` in the end, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

oops! i forgot about `findfile()`!

```
no gf :<c-u>vie <c-r>=findfile(expand('<cfile>'))<cr><cr>
```